# Set icon for Notification in watchOS2

Tags: push-notification, watchos-2, watch-notification

I'm working on `notification` in `watchOS 2`. I want to change icon of notification. I've set *AppIcon* in *ImageAsset* file but this didn't worked.

How can this be achieved?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]Select the `Assets.xcassets` under your `watchApp` folder and create a new image set for `watchOS App Icon` , it will give your all the sizes for icons. Put all the icons over there. Make sure that watch  icons don't contain `alpha channel`.